# Simple type narrowing in if statement fails in Typescript

Tags: typescript, if-statement, typing, type-narrowing

Consider this snippet:

```
const element = {} as { type: string, props: Object } | { type: Function, props: any }
if (typeof element.type === "string") {
    element
}
else {
    element
}
```

In both branches of the if statement, the type of *element* is inferred to be:

```
{
    type: string;
    props: Object;
} | {
    type: Function;
    props: any;
}
```

I would have expected that in the first branch of the if statement, the type of *element* would be `{ type: string; props: Object; }`, and in the second branch, it would be `{ type: Function; props: any; }`

I'm not sure why such basic type narrowing fails.

Comment: I don't know if you do it your way, but these kind of situations are handled with string discriminators. `{ type: 'string' } | { type: 'function' }`. Then type narrowing works with `if (element.type === 'string')`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković I can't use string discriminators in my design. I'm sure this is simple enough for Typescript to do, and I'm sure it had worked in the past, so I'm not sure why it doesn't work now

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this this with a [custom type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

It could look like this.

```
const element = {} as { type: string, props: Object } | { type: Function, props: any }

function isStringType(obj: { type: string, props: Object } | { type: Function, props: any }): obj is { type: string, props: Object } {
  return typeof obj.type === "string";
}

if (isStringType(element)) {
    element // typed as { type: string;  props: Object;}
}
else {
    element // typed as { type: Function; props: any;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Taxel 
But my questions is about why the automatic type narrowing is failing, not what to do about it.